# Is userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) called when app is in foreground but user denied notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to understand if `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` is called when the app is in foreground, but the user denied / turned off the app's notifications?

I see that when I simulate the notification in the simulator (through a `.apns` file), the method is called, even though no matter what I call the completion handler with, the alert won't be shown.

Is this the behavior with actual push notifications as well? I have no way to test this currently.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If the user disabled notifications, the notification won’t arrive at all, so the method won’t be called.

Comment: This is not correct. Notification permission gives permission for an app to *show* notifications. It is not required for an app to register for remote notifications. An app can receive and process silent push notifications without ever asking the user for notification permission.

Comment: But we are not talking about silent notification, aren’t we?

Comment: It doesn't matter; The fact is you can get a push token without asking for notification  permissions.  Once you have a push token you can send pushes. There isn't a separate token for silent vs non-silent.  Also the user can change revoke the notification permission for your app after initially granting it.  This does not invalidate the push token and your server can still send pushes without error. The pushes will arrive on the device but won't be shown if your app doesn't have permission